# Kahler forms of a smooth affine algebra vanish eventually?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, modules

If $k$ is a Noetherian ring, then do the Kahler forms of a smooth affine $k$-algebra of dimension $d$ vanish above $d$?

I mean is: $\Omega^{d+1}_{A|k}\cong 0$?

Comment: Yes. This just follows from the fact that $\Omega_{A/k}$ is locally free of rank $d$, and so locally your module is trivial, so is actually trivial.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: This is a complete answer. Not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This follows precisely from the fact that $\Omega_{A/k}^1$ is locally free of rank $d$ (by smoothness). So, locally $\wedge^{d+1}\Omega_{A^k}^1$ is locally zero, and so globally zero.